# How can I embed a webapp in my own react webapp?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, web-applications, embed

I can run this web app game locally with npm run dev. How can I make it start and run with my react app. I have no idea what to look for help and I am a bit desperate.

In the react app I imported the index.html file of the game and tried running the react app with this:

```
import index from 'html-loader!./micropolisJS/index.html';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <iframe src={index}></iframe>
        );
    }
}
```

But this only shows the contents of the html with no formatting and no function. All the sprites are shown with all of the text that is printed to the screen at some point in the html but no formatting and no function behind any of it. It just says "Hmm. That address doesn’t look right.
Please check that the URL is correct and try again.". I am really at a loss here please send some help .....

Also sometimes I get this error but not every time even without changing anything:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. 
See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the html file, and then render it using jsx

```
let test = <div> {index} </div>;

return (
    <test/>
)
```

For the issue you are mentionning, i would consider to have the html file on the public folder and then fetch it from react using a Get and then render the response using the snippet shown above

Edit :
Can you put the Micropolis folder you want to embed on the public URL of your project then modify iframe src to this :

```
<iframe src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/micropolisJS/index.html'}/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help. I tried exactly this but except an empty <test></test> tag being rendered there is nothing. but I did get another error besides that with my first approach:
``[eslint] 
src/App.js
  Line 3:1:  Unexpected '!' in 'html-loader!./micropolisJS/index.html'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
``

Comment: Actually i believe the error encountered by eslint is when you import it, it tries to load it as an actual js module, i guess fetching the content of the file using an Http Get will prevent this error from happening, and then if the content is fetched it will be a huge string that you can render using the jsx snippet i gave you

Comment: An other idea ( but it's not how i would do in a production env ) you may be able to create a js file that only export a string representation of the html file then export it 
On your render component you could then just import the js and then the snippet should do the trick

Comment: are there any resources you could point me towards? I don't really get what you mean with fetching. I have this file in my filesystem together with all the resources and I can run it locally with npm. But this sounds good in general just I don'T get how I should get a "huge" string from a html file. Also I don't know how to make the other webapp run it's code and not just display the html content